# Error al usar funcion decoradora en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Este es un código para hacer cambio de divisas, el código funciona bien, pero note que unas funciones eran repetitivas y quise colocar una función decoradora para depurar el código, sin embargo me dice error porque la variable que contiene un entry no esta definida, no entiendo porque si en las funciones normales sin decorar también esta esa variable y no me da ese error, acá esta todo el código, la función decoradora con el error esta en la linea 13, y las funciones a decorar se llaman: seleccion1, 2, 3 y 4, que están a partir de la linea 57, el entry esta en la linea 130 y la variable asociada justo arriba. Si tienen algún consejo de que mas se puede depurar en este código también ayudaría, voy comenzando con python.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.config(bg = "#4DFE22")
root.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\familia garia 1.2\Downloads\calculator_coin_dollar_icono.ico")
root.title("Aplicacion de conversion monetaria")

tasa = 0
moneda_a_convertir = 0

#----------------------------------------------FUNCIONES------------------------------------------------
def decorador_selecciones(funcion_a_decorar):
    def funcion_interior(*args, **kwargs):
        global moneda_a_convertir
        entry_tasa.config(state = "normal")
        entry_dolares.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_pesos_colombianos.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares2.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares1.config(state = "disabled")
        funcion_a_decorar(*args, **kwargs)
    return funcion_interior()

def ingresar_tasa():
    global tasa
    global moneda_a_convertir

    tasa = variable_tasa.get()

    if moneda_a_convertir == 1:
        entry_bolivares1.config(state = "normal")
        entry_dolares.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_pesos_colombianos.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares2.config(state = "disabled")

    elif moneda_a_convertir == 2:
        entry_pesos_colombianos.config(state = "normal")
        entry_dolares.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares2.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares1.config(state = "disabled")

    elif moneda_a_convertir == 3:
        entry_bolivares2.config(state = "normal")
        entry_dolares.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_pesos_colombianos.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares1.config(state = "disabled")

    elif moneda_a_convertir == 4:
        entry_dolares.config(state = "normal")
        entry_pesos_colombianos.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares2.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares1.config(state = "disabled")

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Intento de conversion", "Error al ingreasar la moneda a convertir!")

@decorador_selecciones
def seleccion1():
    #global moneda_a_convertir
    #entry_tasa.config(state = "normal")
    moneda_a_convertir = 1

def seleccion2():
    global moneda_a_convertir
    entry_tasa.config(state = "normal")
    moneda_a_convertir = 2

def seleccion3():
    global moneda_a_convertir
    entry_tasa.config(state = "normal")
    moneda_a_convertir = 3

def seleccion4():
    global moneda_a_convertir
    entry_tasa.config(state = "normal")
    moneda_a_convertir = 4

def convertir():
    global moneda_a_convertir
    try:
        if moneda_a_convertir == 1:
            num2 = variable_bolivares_p.get() * tasa
            variable_pesos_colombianos.set(float("{0:.4f}".format(num2)))

        elif moneda_a_convertir == 2:
            num1 = variable_pesos_colombianos.get() / tasa
            variable_bolivares_p.set(float("{0:.4f}".format(num1)))

        elif moneda_a_convertir == 3:
            num4 = variable_bolivares_d.get() / tasa
            variable_doalres.set(float("{0:.4f}".format(num4)))

        elif moneda_a_convertir == 4:
            num3 = variable_doalres.get() * tasa
            variable_bolivares_d.set(float("{0:.4f}".format(num3)))
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Intento de conversion de divisas", "Solo puede ingresar numeros!")

def borrar_campos():
    variable_bolivares_p.set(0)
    variable_pesos_colombianos.set(0)
    variable_bolivares_d.set(0)
    variable_doalres.set(0)

def ayuda():
    messagebox.showinfo("Bienvenido al sistema de cambio de divisas", """Por favor oprima el boton correspondiente al tipo de cambio a realizar
Seguidamente ingrese la tasa de cambio y luego oprima el boton 'ingresar tasa'
Por ultimo ingrese el valor a convertir en la casilla correspondiente y oprima convertir
Su resultado se motrara automaticamente en la casilla superior o inferior.""")

#-----------------------------------------------BOTONES 1------------------------------------------------
frame_botones = Frame(root, bg = "#4DFE22")
frame_botones.pack()

Button(frame_botones, text = "Boliv. >>> Pesos", width = 13, font = ("Lora Bold", 12), command = seleccion1).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 17.5, pady = 35)
Button(frame_botones, text = "Pesos >>> Boliv.", width = 13, font = ("Lora Bold", 12), command = seleccion2).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 17.5, pady = 35)
Button(frame_botones, text = "Boliv. >>> Dolar", width = 13, font = ("Lora Bold", 12), command = seleccion3).grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 17.5, pady = 35)
Button(frame_botones, text = "Dolar >>> Boliv.", width = 13, font = ("Lora Bold", 12), command = seleccion4).grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx = 17.5, pady = 35)

#------------------------------------------------ENTRYS-------------------------------------------------
frame_entrys = Frame(root, bg = "#4DFE22")
frame_entrys.pack()

variable_tasa = DoubleVar()
variable_bolivares_p = DoubleVar()
variable_pesos_colombianos = DoubleVar()
variable_bolivares_d = DoubleVar()
variable_doalres = DoubleVar()

entry_tasa = Entry(frame_entrys, textvariable = variable_tasa, width = 20, font = ("verdana", 10), state= "disabled")
entry_tasa.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 20)
Label(frame_entrys, text = "Tasa actual", font = ("Amaranth", 15), bg = "#4DFE22").grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 20, sticky = "w")
boton_tasa = Button(frame_entrys, text = "Ingresar tasa", width = 15, font = ("Lora Bold", 12), command = ingresar_tasa).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "e")

Label(frame_entrys, bg = "#4DFE22").grid(row = 2, column = 0)
Label(frame_entrys, bg = "#4DFE22").grid(row = 3, column = 0)

entry_pesos_colombianos = Entry(frame_entrys, textvariable = variable_pesos_colombianos, width = 20, font = ("verdana", 10), state = "disabled")
entry_pesos_colombianos.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 20)
Label(frame_entrys, text = "Pesos Colombianos", font = ("Amaranth", 15), bg = "#4DFE22").grid(row = 4, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 20, sticky = "w")

entry_bolivares1 = Entry(frame_entrys, textvariable = variable_bolivares_p, width = 20, font = ("verdana", 10), state = "disabled")
entry_bolivares1.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 20)
Label(frame_entrys, text = "Bolivares", font = ("Amaranth", 15), bg = "#4DFE22").grid(row = 5, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 20, sticky = "w")

Label(frame_entrys, bg = "#4DFE22").grid(row = 6, column = 0)
Label(frame_entrys, bg = "#4DFE22").grid(row = 7, column = 0)

entry_dolares = Entry(frame_entrys, textvariable = variable_doalres, width = 20, font = ("verdana", 10), state = "disabled")
entry_dolares.grid(row = 8, column = 1, padx = 20)
Label(frame_entrys, text = "Dolares", font = ("Amaranth", 15), bg = "#4DFE22").grid(row = 8, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 20, sticky = "w")

entry_bolivares2 = Entry(frame_entrys, textvariable = variable_bolivares_d, width = 20, font = ("verdana", 10), state = "disabled")
entry_bolivares2.grid(row = 9, column = 1, padx = 20)
Label(frame_entrys, text = "Bolivares", font = ("Amaranth", 15), bg = "#4DFE22").grid(row = 9, column = 0, pady = 10, padx = 20, sticky = "w")

#-----------------------------------------------BOTONES 2------------------------------------------------
frame_botones2 = Frame(root, bg = "#4DFE22")
frame_botones2.pack()

Button(frame_botones2, text = "Convertir", width = 15, font = ("Lora Bold", 12), command = convertir).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 25, pady = 10)
Button(frame_botones2, text = "Borrar Campos", width = 15, font = ("Lora Bold", 12), command = borrar_campos).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 25, pady = 10)
Button(frame_botones2, text = "Ayuda", width = 15, font = ("Lora Bold", 12), command = ayuda).grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 25, pady = 10)

messagebox.showinfo("Bienvenido al sistema de cambio de divisas", """Bienvenido!
Por favor oprima el boton correspondiente al tipo de cambio a realizar
Seguidamente ingrese la tasa de cambio y luego oprima el boton 'ingresar tasa'
Por ultimo ingrese el valor a convertir en la casilla correspondiente y oprima convertir
Su resultado se motrara automaticamente en la casilla superior o inferior.""")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función decoradora debe retornar la función interna, esto es:

```
def decorador_selecciones(funcion_a_decorar):
    def funcion_interior(*args, **kwargs):
        global moneda_a_convertir
        entry_tasa.config(state = "normal")
        entry_dolares.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_pesos_colombianos.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares2.config(state = "disabled")
        entry_bolivares1.config(state = "disabled")
        funcion_a_decorar(*args, **kwargs)
    return funcion_interior
```

En cambio lo que tú tenías retornaba `funcion_interior()`, que es *el resultado de ejecutar* la función interna, que no es lo mismo.

### Un poco de teoría

Un decorador es una función `f`, que recibe como parámetro otra función `g` y retorna como resultado una tercera función `k`. Es decir, cuando haces `f(g)` el resultado es `k`, que es otra función.

Cuando usas la sintaxis de decoración así:

```
@f
def g():
   ...
```

lo que está ocurriendo en realidad es esto:

```
def g():
   ...
g = f(g)
```

Es decir, se llama al decorador `f` pasándole como parámetro la función `g`, y la función (`k`) resultante se asigna a `g`. De este modo, cuando en lo sucesivo el programa haga `g()` ya no estará llamando a la `g` definida en el `def`, pues la hemos redefinido. En su lugar estará llamando a `k()`.

Comment: Una duda! ya se resolvio el problema, sin embargo al principio no me servia tampoco, pero note que en parte si funcionada, y el problema estaba en la variable global moneda_a_convertir, la cual no le estaba cambiando el valor, como si no la estuviera tomando como variable global, por lo que esa linea la saque de la funcion decoradora ( global moneda_a_convertir ), y funciona perfectamente! alguna idea de porque sea eso? no se pueden colocar variables globales dentro de una funcion decoradora? Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: No entiendo esta duda... Las variables globales no necesitan ser declaradas dentro de  las funciones **a no ser** que la función vaya a modificar la variable global. Sólo para leerla no necesitas declararla. Si vas a cambiarle el valor dentro de la función, sí necesitas. No obstante tu decorador, aunque declara esa variable como global, no la usa, por tanto esa declaración sobra. Las que sí tienen que declararla como global son las funciones decoradas (pues le asignan un valor)

Comment: Si esa era la duda! porque cada una de las funciones modifica el valor de la variable global, pero todas la declaran y como esa linea tambien se repetia queria ponerla tambien en la decoradora, pero no sabia que tienen que declararse siempre dentro de la misma funcion que la modificara por tanto no la puedo declarar en la decoradora, Gracias problema resuelto!